# DotNetOpenAuth and C# desktop application

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, dotnetopenauth

I'm using `DotNetOpenAuth` (http://dotnetopenauth.net/)  library to authenticate at [linkedIn.com](http://linkedIn.com). I develop a desktop application and now I'm a little confused. I'm unaware if it's possible to authenticate using a desktop application.

Does anybody know? If it's possible please show me how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it depends on how you want to approach it, but maybe looking at the DesktopConsumer class in the API might point you in the right direction: http://docs.dotnetopenauth.net/v3.4/html/T_DotNetOpenAuth_OAuth_DesktopConsumer.htm

One example usage as a desktop app is detailed here: http://developer.yahoo.com/forum/Fantasy-Sports-API/Authenticating-with-NET-using-DotNetOpenAuth/1279209867000-4eee22f1-25fd-3589-9115-1a835add3212