# Single sign-on for a .NET desktop application (Google, Yahoo, Facebook ...)

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, single-sign-on

I need to provide a login mechanism in my application. I'd would like to provide login for the most common IPs, such as *Google*, *Yahoo!*, *Facebook*, *Microsoft Live* and others.

My application is a **Desktop application** written in C#, so **is not** a Web application.

- Do you know any library or framework that I could use to achieve this purpose.
- Must I implement a sign-on mechanism for each provider?

NOTE: I know that Microsoft provides a [unique sign-on mechanism](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/identity/) in Azure, but I'm not interested in this Azure service.

Comment: Do you want to use open auth? There is an answer for that framework here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591460/dotnetopenauth-and-c-sharp-desktop-application

Comment: My question is if there is any framework or library that already implements it, yes I suppose that that library should use OpenAuth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OpenAuth](http://oauth.net) will do what you need, but it can be complicated to use. There are an abundance of resources to help you, though. [Here](http://www.deanhume.com/Home/BlogPost/a-simple-guide-to-using-oauth-with-c-/49) is a link to an article describing the process of using OAuth, and there is an excellent SO answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4463378/376474) with code samples you can use to get started.

You will need to register with the services you'd like to use for sign on and receive a key for them. Quoted from the linked article:

> 1. Register your app with the service that you are developing it for. e.g. Twitter, Twitpic, SoundCloud etc. You will receive a consumer key and secret.
> 2. You, the developer of the app then initiates the OAuth process by passing the consumer key and the consumer secret
> 3. The service will return a Request Token to you.
> 4. The user then needs to grant approval for the app to run requests.
> 5. Once the user has granted permission you need to exchange the request token for an access token.
> 6. Now that you have received an access token, you use this to sign all http requests with your credentials and access token.

Though you will need a key from each provider, the method of authentication will be the same, so you will not actually need to implement separate sign on code specific to each service provider.